# Emacs Info manual error "No such node or anchor: Top"

Tags: emacs, info

While trying to follow links from main Info page (`C-h i` then `RET` on the topic) or trying to open any Info file directly (`C-u C-h i`), I get the following error:

```
No such node or anchor: Top
```

I'm using emacs-25.3_1 for Windows.
Everything was working fine, I didn't change anything that I think should affect this functionality, then it just stopped working.

`Info-directory-list` contains a path to valid `.info` files.

```
user-error: No such node or anchor: Top
```

Comment: Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: `emacs -Q` did the trick.

Comment: If you found the answer, and you think the question & answer might be helpful to others, please consider posting the answer (and you can accept it). If you think what you learned won't be very helpful to others you might want to instead just delete the question. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`openwith` package](https://github.com/emacsmirror/openwith) was causing the problem.  Through process of elimination, discovered `(require 'openwith)` was causing the problem.  Tested several times to ensure.  Commented out, restarted (just `eval-buffer` wasn't enough) and everything is working fine.